# fetch 'Object' type data from sanity CMS

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I am working on a blog project built with nextJS, typescript. I have successfully been able to fetch data from sanity CMS. I am able to see the 'blog_title, author_name, description and etc'. The problem I am having with its 'body' or blog content. The body structure from sanity CMS is below:

[image]

The blog I have added to the database, where the body part is stored as an object. So, I have created the type defition like this:

```
export interface Post {
  _id: string
  _createdAt: string
  title: string
  author: {
    name: string
    image: string
  }
  description: string
  mainImage: {
    asset: {
      url: string
    }
  }
  slug: {
    current: string
  }
  body: [object]
}
```

**Here everything is working properly when I call the props the blog details and works perfect:**

```
        <h1>
          {post.title}
        </h1>
        <h2>
          {post.description}
        </h2>
        <div>
          <img
            src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()}
            alt=""
          />
          <p>
            Blog posted by{' '}
            <span>
              {post.author.name}
            </span>{' '}
            - Published at {post._createdAt}
          </p>
        </div>
```

I tried destructuring the 'body' object to able to access the content.
I also saw there is one library in sanity, named "PortableText" which is used to render this type of content and has default parameter value. I tried like this:

```
<PortableText value={post.body}/>
```

shows this error:

```
Type '[object]' is not assignable to type 'TypedObject | TypedObject[]'.
```

**What should I do?**